# Taking comma delimited data and creating a column for each section, while specifying in other rows when the section is not present

Tags: csv, unix, awk

Can't really be done with just a simple `tr "," "\t"` or `awk 'BEGIN {FS = ",";OFS = "\t"}'` because I want the other rows to say when the variable is not present.

I want take something of this format

```
R#  C#  m's add de's
18  5   0   +3,+9   0
18  6   0   0   0
20  22  m(9;22)(q34;q11),m(9;22)    0   de(9)(q21q31)
20  23  m(9;22)(q34;q11),m(3;17),m(9;22)    +8,+4   de(10)(q24),de(21)(p12)
```

And produce something of this format

```
R#  C#  m's                                 add             de's
R#  C#  m(9;22)(q34;q11)    m(9;22) m(3;17) +3  +9  +8  +4  de(9)(q21q31)   del(10)(q24)    de(21)(p12)
18  5   0   0   0   +3  +9  0   0   0   0   0
18  6   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
20  22  m(9;22)(q34;q11)    m(9;22) 0   0   0   0   0   de(9)(q21q31)   0   0
20  23  m(9;22)(q34;q11)    m(9;22) m(3;17) 0   0   +8  +4  0   de(10)(q24) de(21)(p12)
```

Basically what I want to do is take a file with tab delimited format where the m combinations followed by things in brackets, the + signs followed by a number and the de's followed by things in brackets and instead of just having them separated by a bracket within a column, I want each one that is different to have it's own column as well as a 0 in every other row for when that line does not have that particular column. Sorry for the confusing explanation but hopefully the example is good.

Smaller example
the m(9;22)(q34;q11),m(3;17),m(9;22) for example will produce threw columns in the output where if the row possesses this part of information then this part of information will show up in that row, or a 0 otherwise
like from

Input:

```
R#  C#  m's
20  23  m(9;22)(q34;q11),m(3;17),m(9;22)
24  25  m(9;22)
26  27  m(12,19)(q31;q12)
```

Output:

```
R#  C#  m's
R#  C#  m(9;22)(q34;q11)   m(3;17)   m(9;22)    m(12,19)(q31;q12)
20  23  m(9;22)(q34;q11)   m(3;17)   m(9;22)    0
24  25  0   0   m(9;22) 0
26  27  0   0   0   m(12,19)(q31;q12)
```

EDIT:

The line containing

```
 R# C#  m's                                 add             de's
```

is not absolutely necessary but would be nice
The line containing

```
R#  C#  m(9;22)(q34;q11)    m(9;22) m(3;17) +3  +9  +8  +4  de(9)(q21q31)   del(10)(q24)    de(21)(p12)
```

is necessary, it is a label for the columns

All input is coming from a file of about 60,000 lines

Bascially if anything shows up in the file like de(9)(q21q31)
Then there will be a column made for it
If a row possesses "de(9)(q21q31)" then "de(9)(q21q31)" under the column with the header "de(9)(q21q31)" and if this row does not contain "de(9)(q21q31)" then a 0 will be printed in this row underneath this column

Comment: Is each line processed in isolation, or does the parsing of line 2 in your data (`18 5 0 +3,+9 0`) need to know about the number of columns in the last line shown?   It really isn't clear to me — I probably could (but definitely shouldn't — and probably shouldn't have to) spend the time working it out.  The input has tab-separated fields; the output needs to be tab-separated but the commas also need to be replaced by tabs, and there are zero-columns to add to, I believe.

Comment: your `t` and `m` prefixes changed on last row, intentional?

Comment: You haven't specified how you know that, for instance, the `0` in row 3 column 3 of the input is supposed to represent 3 columns of output. Is it only because row 5 column 3 consists of 3 comma-separated values? Can a later row contain even more such values in column 3?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Sorry I'm not quite sure what you're asking but I posted another example if it's helpful

Comment: So, if I'm reading the tea-leaves correctly, in a given data file, the number of columns in the input is fixed (and the number of fields is not less than 3), and the fields are tab-delimited.  To know what must be output, the code must scan each of the fields from 3..NF and determine what is the maximum number of commas in any of the input lines.  It can then generate the output data, (re)processing each input line in turn.  For a given field from 3..NF, it must generate as many output fields as there are in the line with the maximum number of commas in the same field. _[…continued…]_

Comment: _[…continuation…]_ It must also add a column containing 0 after those fields.  It is not entirely clear whether the second comment line must be generated as well, and what it must contain.  It so happens that the sample inputs have a single line with the maximum number of comma-separated sub-fields in each column.  Can it be the case that there could be 3 sub-fields in column 3 of line 1 and none in columns 4 and 5, while line 2 has 2 sub-fields in column 3 and 2 sub-fields in column 4 and none in column 5, and line 33 has no sub-fields in columns 3 or 4 but has 4 sub-fields in column 5? _[…]_

Comment: _[…]_ If there can be a mixture like that, what is output in the second line?  Or is that not needed in the output after all (it is _only_ a comment, at least to naïve eyes).  How big are the data files you're dealing with?  What is the maximum number of columns, the maximum number of sub-fields in any column, the maximum number of rows?  Is the data coming strictly from a file, or could it be from a non-seekable source such as a pipe or socket?  This affects whether the code must store the input data for reprocessing, or what. If the file sizes are less than gigabytes, it may not matter much.

Comment: I tried to answer your questions in an edit, does it make sense now? For some of your other confusion it's not really looking for the row with the most commas because if row 1 possesses +8.+9,+11 and row 2 has +12,+13+15 within it then a column will be made for all of +8 +9 +11 +12 +13 +15. All of the original column headers will most likely have sub columns, but possibly not. @JonathanLeffler

Comment: Your update says the first comment line in the output is optional.  Pity; that's easy.  In the second sample output, why are there 2 leading zeros on the row starting `24 25`?  Why are there 3 leading zeros and no trailing zero on the row starting `26 27`?  Why are the column labels important when the list off column labels is incomplete — the trailing zero columns (assuming they're required) don't get column labels in the output.  Your question is still under-specified.  It is an arcane reformatting exercise — entirely non-trivial — but it is much harder when the specification is incomplete.

Comment: Referring to your "I tried to answer" comment — Hmm; now I'm wholly confused.  We have to keep track of the unique sub-field values in a given input field, and there needs to be an output column for each such unique value?  With zeros in the output columns when the input row doesn't have the corresponding sub-field.  Are the extra zeros still needed? It seems clear that this requires two-pass processing of the data. We can't tell what the output columns in the first (data) row should be until we've read all the inputs. 60k lines isn't too bad as long as the lines aren't themselves several KiB.

Comment: The row starting with 24 25 has two leading zeroes because it does not contain m(9;22)(q34;q11)   or m(3;17), so 0 is printed there as a way of saying, "false, this row does not contain that piece of information". The last row does not have a trailing 0 because the input last line contains "m(12,19)(q31;q12)" whereas all the other rows do not contain this so a zero is printed to say that that piece of information is not in those rows @JonathanLeffler

Comment: @JonathanLeffler There are no extra zeroes except in the sense that all the zeroes are extra. The zeroes are to say that the row they are in does not contain the piece of information which is specified by the column header

Comment: OK; beginning to understand the requirements now.  I shouldn't have spent this time on it (there's this 'work' thingie that I'm supposed to pay attention to).  It will be a lot later (6+ hours) before I look again.  I hope someone else will be able to help before then.

Comment: `m(12,19)` should be `m(12;19)` in your second input file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a decidedly non-trivial exercise, but I think this code produces the correct output for both the data samples in the question.

#### File `script.awk`:

```
NR == 1 { print; hdr1 = $1; hdr2 = $2; next }
        {
            line++;
            #print line ": [", $0, "]"
            col1[line] = $1
            col2[line] = $2
            for (field = 3; field <= NF; field++)
            {
                if ($field == "0") continue
                n = split($field, a, ",")
                for (sf = 1; sf <= n; sf++)
                {
                    val = a[sf]
                    x = field SUBSEP val
                    if (x in sf_idx)
                        idx = sf_idx[x]
                    else
                    {
                        idx = ++sf_cnt[field]
                        sf_idx[field, val] = idx
                        sf_val[field, idx] = val
                    }
                    cols[line,field,idx] = 1
                    #printf "cols[%d][%d][%d] = %s\n", line, field, idx, cols[line, field, idx]
                }
            }
            if (max_nf < NF)
                max_nf = NF
        }
END     {
            max_line = line
            #print "Lines:", max_line, "; fields:", max_nf
            # Line 2 heading
            printf "#%s   %s", hdr1, hdr2
            for (field = 3; field <= max_nf; field++)
            {
                for (sf = 1; sf <= sf_cnt[field]; sf++)
                    printf "   %s", sf_val[field, sf]
            }
            print ""
            # Data lines
            for (line = 1; line <= max_line; line++)
            {
                printf "%s   %s", col1[line], col2[line]
                for (field = 3; field <= max_nf; field++)
                {
                    #print "field:", field, "sub-fields:", sf_cnt[field]
                    for (sf = 1; sf <= sf_cnt[field]; sf++)
                    {
                        #print "line:", line, "; field:", field, "; sf:", sf
                        x = line SUBSEP field SUBSEP sf
                        if (x in cols)
                            val = sf_val[field, sf]
                        else
                            val = "0"
                        printf "   %s", val
                    }
                }
                print ""
            }
        }
```

#### Explanation

This code assumes that the data set is small enough that the data can be kept in memory so that there is no need to rescan the file.  If your files are truly enormous and/or you don't have much memory on your machine, you can revise the code to read the file multiple times, but it isn't clear that it will really save all that much memory.

Data:

- `sf_cnt[field]` records the number of different sub-field in the field
- `sf_idx[field, value]` records the column number where a given `value` should be printed
- `sf_val[field, index]` records the sub-field value for a given index value
- `col1` records the value in column 1 for each line
- `col2` records the value in column 2 for each line
- `cols` records which combinations of line, field and sub-field are non-zero.

Code:

The `NR == 1` block prints the first line and captures the headings for columns 1 and 2.

The 'for every row' block:

- Increments line number and captures columns 1 and 2.
- For each field from 3 to the end

  - It ignores fields containing a 0
  - It splits the field on commas into the array `a`, with the number of sub-fields saved in `n`
  - For each sub-field
  - Determine the value in sub-field
  - If sub-field is already found as an index in `sf_idx[field, value]`

    - Use the value in `sf_idx[field][value]` as `idx`
  - Else

    - Increment the number of unique field values in this field (`sf_cnt`)
    - Save the index for the combination of field number and value
    - Save the value for the combination of field number and index
  - Record that the combination of line, field and index number are in `cols`
- Record the maximum number of fields in a line

The 'END' block
* Prints the second line of output, using the saved column names and the values in `sf_val`.
* For each line of input:
  * Outputs the first two column names
  * For each field
    * For each sub-field
      * If the line, field, sub-field is recorded in `cols`, then the value to be printed is the value in `sf_val[field, sf]`
      * Else the value is `0`
      * Print the value with leading white space
  * Print a newline

#### File `data.1`

```
R#  C#  m's add de's
18  5   0   +3,+9   0
18  6   0   0   0
20  22  m(9;22)(q34;q11),m(9;22)    0   de(9)(q21q31)
20  23  m(9;22)(q34;q11),m(3;17),m(9;22)    +8,+4   de(10)(q24),de(21)(p12)
```

#### File `data.2`:

```
R#  C#  m's
20  23  m(9;22)(q34;q11),m(3;17),m(9;22)
24  25  m(9;22)
26  27  m(12;19)(q31;q12)
```

Note that `m(12,19)` was changed to `m(12;19)` in this file.

#### Example outputs:

Using `column -t` presents the columns conveniently formatted for reading.

```
$ awk -f script.awk data.2 | column -t
R#   C#  m's
#R#  C#  m(9;22)(q34;q11)  m(3;17)  m(9;22)  m(12;19)(q31;q12)
20   23  m(9;22)(q34;q11)  m(3;17)  m(9;22)  0
24   25  0                 0        m(9;22)  0
26   27  0                 0        0        m(12;19)(q31;q12)
$

$ awk -f script.awk data.1 | column -t
R#   C#  m's               add      de's
#R#  C#  m(9;22)(q34;q11)  m(9;22)  m(3;17)  +3  +9  +8  +4  de(9)(q21q31)  de(10)(q24)  de(21)(p12)
18   5   0                 0        0        +3  +9  0   0   0              0            0
18   6   0                 0        0        0   0   0   0   0              0            0
20   22  m(9;22)(q34;q11)  m(9;22)  0        0   0   0   0   de(9)(q21q31)  0            0
20   23  m(9;22)(q34;q11)  m(9;22)  m(3;17)  0   0   +8  +4  0              de(10)(q24)  de(21)(p12)
$
```

The output only uses spaces; you can readily replace the triple-spaces in the `awk` script formatting with tabs if that's what's desired.

Answer (score 0):

I guess something like this should work.  Preprocessed the file to split commas (can be done in awk as well).  Also a double-pass algorithm, which can be converted to single pass as well.  You can add the first header easily.

```
$ awk -f col.awk xfile{,} | column -t

R#  C#  m(12;19)(q31;q12)  m(3;17)  m(9;22)  m(9;22)(q34;q11)
20  23  m(9;22)(q34;q11)   m(3;17)  m(9;22)  0
24  25  0                  0        m(9;22)  0
26  27  0                  0        0        m(12;19)(q31;q12)
```

where

```
$ cat col.awk

NR == FNR {
  if (NR > 1) for (i = 3; i <= NF; i++) if (!($i in a)) a[$i] = ++c
  next
}

NR != FNR && FNR == 1   {
  n = asorti(a, b)
  printf "%s", $1 OFS $2
  for (i = 1; i <= n; i++) printf "%s", OFS b[i]
  print ""
  next
}

{
  for (i = 3; i <= NF; i++) if ($i in a) f[a[$i]] = $i
  printf "%s", $1 OFS $2
  for (i = 1; i <= n; i++) printf "%s", OFS (i in f ? f[i] : 0)
  print ""
  delete f
}
```

and

```
$ tr ',' ' ' <file >xfile
```